# Delete the line breaks on those lines without a point a the end using sed

Tags: file, sed, point, lines

I have a file with several lines but the last character of the lines is not always a point. So, How to find a delete the line breaks on those lines without a point a the end using sed?

Comment: Do you mean "period" instead of "point"?

Comment: It's like when you copy a paragraph from a pdf and paste it on a simple text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier in Perl:

```
perl -pe 'chomp unless /\.$/'
```

You might need to add a space, though:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / unless /\.$/'
```